# Deleting image from wordpress frontend

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

This is the current code which is displaying the images on the frontend gallery.

What i need is a link or button to delete a single image when pressed.
It should show a confirmation javascript alert before deleting and then delete 
Don't need ajax just plain javascript page refreshes is no issue.

I have looked out over the internet but can't really find a good  solution.

```
    function Closify_Translate_Images_to_Photoswipe_HTML($galleries, $effect, 
    $random_id, $itemPerPage = 10, $disable_caption = "off", $imgWidth = '', 
    $titleEnabled = 'off', $isMultiPage)
     {
      // Update caption flag
      $caption = ($disable_caption!="on")?true:false;

      $itemWidth = '';

      // Update title flag
      $title = ($titleEnabled!="on")?true:false;

      // Update item's width
      if($imgWidth != '') $itemWidth = ';width:'.$imgWidth.'px;';

      // Update option range
      $options = '';
      for($i=10;$i<35;$i=$i+5)
      {
        if($i==$itemPerPage){
            $options = $options . '<option selected>'.$i.'</option>';
        }else{
            $options = $options . '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
      }

      $numPages = '';
      if($isMultiPage){
        $itemWidth = $itemWidth.'opacity:0;';
        $numPages = '<form class="closify-jpages-form">
            <label>items per page: </label>
            <select id="closify-select-'.$random_id.'">
                '.$options.'
            </select>
        </form>';
     }

      $holder = '<div class="closify-holder closify-holder-'.$random_id.'"> 
 </div>';
    $htmlStart = '<div id="itemContainer-'.$random_id.'" class="closify-gallery" 
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">';
    $htmlEnd = '</div>';
    $htmlBody = '';
    $titleText = "";
    $captionText = "";
    $titleCopyright = "";

    foreach($galleries as $gallery)
    {
        if($caption && $gallery['img_desc']!='') 
            $captionText = '<br>Description <small>'.$gallery['img_desc'].'</small>';
        else
            $captionText = "";

        if($title) 
            $titleText = 'Title <small>'.$gallery['img_title'].'</small>';

        $htmlBody = $htmlBody.'<figure class="closify-figure-gallery-item" style="'.$itemWidth.'" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <a href="'.$gallery['full'][0].'" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="'.$gallery['full'][1].'x'.$gallery['full'][2].'">
                <img class="closify-animated '.$effect.'" src="'.$gallery['thumb'][0].'" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="'.$gallery['img_alt'].'" />
            </a>
            <figcaption itemprop="caption description">'.$titleText.$captionText.'</figcaption>
        </figure>';



    }


    return $numPages.$holder.$htmlStart.$htmlBody.$htmlEnd;
}
```

Comment: When you say delete, do you mean just from the gallery, or from the site so the image is no longer stored there?

Comment: Delete permanently

Answer (score 0):

From the server side there will be only one PHP file that should process the images that have been uploaded from the client side, and this single processing file is represented by the "processupload.php" file. This file is responsible of generating proper photos/thumbnails, where the resized photos are sent back to the client side using AJAX to be shown to the user seamlessly.

Referance link : 
http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/closify-powerful-flexible-image-uploader/full_screen_preview/8292742

```
   ############ Put your custom code here ##############

    This means that you can harness this space to add your own logic.

    Other specific places to look:
1.
    /****************************************************/
    /****************************************************/
    /*
    // Insert info into database table!
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO myImageTable (ImageName, ThumbName, ImgPath)
    VALUES ($DestRandImageName, $thumb_DestRandImageName, 'uploads/')");
    /****************************************************/
    /****************************************************/
2. 
    // Handling position save command
    if(isset($_POST["top"]) || isset($_POST["left"]))
    {
        // When somebody saves a picture you can read "top" and "left" and save them, so it become stored
        // play with "left / top" image position
        echo "Success";
    }

    // Handling image delete command
    // POST
    // command: delete
    // id: The ID name of the specific image container that has been deleted
    if(isset($_POST["command"]) && isset($_POST["id"]))
    {
        // When somebody delete a picture, the corresponding action should be put here

        echo "Deleted";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply what i want is to remove / delete image from the live gallery which can be seen here https://www.itechflare.com/demo/closify-press/  in the uploader the delete option is working but i need a delete on the gallery where these images are shown